# How to set tags in device twin, while registration of device hartcoded from the azure-iot-sdk-c

Tags: tags, azure-iot-sdk

I am working with the azure-iot-c-sdk and I have registered my device to IoT Hub with the dps using x509 certificates. Now I want some changes to the generated device twin during the registration process. I have the ability to set device twin changes in the enrollment group. But I want to hardcode the changes from SDK to know how to set tags to use parameters afterwards while running code.

This is a small snippet of the generated device twin:

```
"modelId": "",
"version": 2,
"properties": {
    "desired": {
        "$metadata": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2022-01-20T16:50:36.3100106Z"
        },
        "$version": 1
    },
    "reported": {
        "$metadata": {
            "$lastUpdated": "2022-01-20T16:50:36.3100106Z"
        },
        "$version": 1
    }
},
```

I want the device twin in this form:

```
"modelId": "",
    "version": 2,
    "tags": {},
        "ADUGroup": "Group1"
    "properties": {
        "desired": {
            ...
        },
        "reported": {
            ...
        }
    },
```

How can I solve this. Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

tags can be only configured from the cloud end and not from the device, so you have to use service SDK's, Portal or  IoTHub CLI/Rest API. They are like cloud properties assigned to the device. The device has no access to the tags element in the twin.

If requirement is to set properties from device to its cloud twin, then you need to push that as reported properties from the device.

Comment: Thx for your help!

Do I understand correctly that I have to use one of these [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-hub-service-sdks) in order to be able to define the tags in the device twin?

I wouldn't use the Portal, now I'm try to use the CLI to automate this process

Comment: Thats correct, the service SDK is what you will need or the CLI or IoTHub REST APIs.